# What's the right way to gather data from different microservices?

Tags: node.js, architecture, microservices

I'm having a problem understanding how basic communication between microservices should be made and I haven't been able to find a good solution or standard way to do this in the other questions. Let's use this basic example.

[image]

I have an invoice service that return **invoices**, every invoice will contain information(ids) about the user and the products. If I have a view in which I need to render the invoices for a specific user, I just make a simple request.

```
let url = "http://my-domain.com/api/v2/invoices"
let params = {userId:1}
request(url,params,(e,r)=>{
  const results = r // An array of 1000 invoices for the user 1
});
```

Now, for this specific **view** I will need to make another request to get all the details for each product on each invoice.

```
results.map((invoice)=>{
   invoice.items.map((itemId)=>{
      const url=`http://my-domain.com/api/v2/products/${itemId}`
      request(url,(e,r)=>{
       const product = r
       //Do something else.....
      });
   });
});
```

I know the code example is not perfect but you can see that this will generate a huge number of requests(at least 1000) to the product service and just for 1 user, now imagine if I have 1000 users making this kind of requests.

What is the right way to get the information off all the products without having to make this number of requests in order to avoid performance issues?.

I found some workarounds for this kind of scenarios such as:

1. Create an API endpoint that accepts a list of IDs in order to make a single request.
2. Duplicate the information from the Product service within the invoice service and find a way to keep them in sync.

In a microservices architecture are these the right ways to deal with this kind of issues? For me, they look like simple workarounds.

***Edit #1: Based on Remus Rusanu response.***

As per Remus recommendation, I decided to isolate my services and describe them a little bit better.

[image]

As shown in the image above the microservices are now isolated(in specific the Billing-service) and they now are the owners of the data. By using this structure I ensure that Billing-service is able to work even if there are async jobs or even if the other two services are down.

If I need to create a new invoice, I can call the other two microservices(Users, Inventory) synchronously and then update the data on the "cache" tables(Users, Inventory) in my billing service.

Is it also good to assume these "cache" tables are read-only? I assume they are since only the user/inventory services should be able to modify this information to preserve isolation and authority over the information.

Comment: Option 1 looks the right solution to me. Why do you think it's a workaround? Option 2 defeats the purpose of micro service. You can have out of sync data and many other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to isolate the services as so they do not share state/data. The design in your question is a single macroservice split into 3 correlated storage silos. Case in point, you cannot interpret a result form the 'Invoicing' service w/o correlating the data with the 'Products' response(s).

Isolated microservices mean they own their data and they can operate independently. An invoice is complete as returned from the 'Invoices' service. It contains the product names, the customer name, every information on the invoice. All the data came from its own storage. A separate microservice could be 'Inventory', that operates all the product inventories, current stock etc. It would also have its own data, in its own storage. A 'product' can exist in both storage mediums, and there once was logical link between them (when the invoice was created), but the link is severed now. The 'Inventory' microservice can change its products (eg. remove one, add new SKUs etc) w/o affecting the existing Invoices (this is not only a microservice isolation requirement, is also a basic accounting requirement). I'm not going to enter here into details of what is a product 'identity' in real life.

If you find yourself asking questions like you're asking it likely means you do not have microservices. You should think at your microservice boundaries while considering what happens if you replace all communication with async queued based requests (a response can come 6 days later): If the semantics break, the boundary is probably wrong. If the semantics hold, is the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, My understanding of this response is that my services should store data that belong to other services in order to make it available without having to depend on the other services to work properly(isolation). If this assumption is correct, then the Edit #1 from the answer details should Illustrate this separation.

Comment: That's right. Each microservice owns its data. Data becomes denormalized, duplicated and often out-of-sync, with an eventual-consistent target.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the resilience requirements that you have. Do you want your microservice to function when the other microservices are down or not?

The first solution that you presented is the less resilient: if any of the Users or Products microservices goes down, the Invoice microservice would also go down. Is this what you want? On the other hand, this architecture is the simplest. A variation of this architecture is to let the client make the join requests; this leads to a chatty conversation but it has the advantage that the client could replace the missing information with default information when the other microservices are down.

The second solution offers the biggest possible resilience but it's more complex. Having an event-driven architecture helps a lot in this case. In this architecture the microservices act as [swimming lanes](http://theartofscalability.com/). A failure in one of the microservices does not propagate to other microservices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I assume that by event-driven you mean that everytime something that matters(according to the bounded context) to the foreign services changes in the user/inventory service, it will trigger an event to let the billing-service it needs to update the local copy of the data, if this is the case, my question from the Edit #1 is answered.

Comment: @Geoffrey-ap yes.

Comment: @Geoffrey-ap from your edit I see that you understood correctly regarding the local representation of remote data but not about the communication style: you should use asynchronous communication.

Comment: @Geoffrey-ap regarding readonlyness: yes, they are immutable; see Value Objects and Anti Corruption Layer  from DDD